# visual studio 2015 c++ editor broken, solution?

Tags: visual-c++, editor

After an install in VS2015 (intel mkl library with vs integration) the c/c++ editor fails to show anything except the tab on top. No window, no text, nothing.
I dug a bit deeper: a .txt file displays fine, .cs as well. When I set in options that filetype .txt needs editing in C/C++ editor, .txt stopped displaying too.
I have compared every option in tools->options, including the environment options, to a normal working rig, found nothing.
Resetting to default options did not help, nor did changing the color scheme.
Removed the Intel directory from common7/IDE/extensions, no improvement.
I do not know where more secrets are kept, tried a registry search, but found no clues. Everything appears to match, up to the dll for language specialization in vxpackages.
Anyone, before I try to repair the installation?
Thanks in advance,
Jan

Edit: I got the editor back on track by disabling Productivity Power Tools 2015. This took me half a day. Any connection to the Intel install is doubtful!